# Using linked lists with Bison

Tags: malloc, bison

Suppose my YYSTYPE is a struct with a pointer to the next struct. Can I direct that pointer to YYSTYPE values of other grammar variables, or are their YYSTYPE values local and will disappear after the derivation ends, causing a segfault later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YYSTYPE is the type of variables on Yacc's expression stack.

If the pointers you create are to items actually stored in Yacc's stack, which would typically be done by referencing `$1` (or `&$1` to get the pointer), then you are indeed pointing to data that will be released and reused, and are in for a world of hurt (such as segmentation faults if you're lucky; confusion and mishandled information if you're unlucky).

If the pointers you create are to items of type YYSTYPE that you manage, then of course there is no problem; you manage their duration, not Yacc.

Copy anything you need from things like `$1` into your own storage.